# Does a void method call count as an expression?

Tags: java, expression

In this Java docs tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

System.out.println(), which is a void method call does not count as an expression, but in this link from the specs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

It is said that an expression can be something that evaluates to nothing (void). This leads to my question and confusion about if a void method call would count as an expression or not in Java? What is the reasoning behind it as well?

Answer (score 1):

A call to a void method is still an expression. All method invocations are (primary) expressions, as specified by the [production rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8):

```
Primary:
  PrimaryNoNewArray 
  ArrayCreationExpression
PrimaryNoNewArray:
  Literal 
  ClassLiteral 
  this 
  TypeName . this 
  ( Expression ) 
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression 
  FieldAccess 
  ArrayAccess 
  MethodInvocation <----
  MethodReference
```

It's just that other rules in the language makes you unable to do much with it. Such an expression is of type `void`. You can't declare a variable of type `void`. `void` does not have any members, etc.

One place where the fact that void method calls are expressions becomes important is in lambda expression bodies. Consider the [production rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaBody):

```
LambdaBody:
  Expression 
  Block
```

If void method calls were not expressions, you would not be able to write:

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println();
```

The above only works because `System.out.println()` is an expression and hence can be used as a lambda body. If it were not an expression, you would have to use a block:

```
Runnable r = () -> { System.out.println(); };
```

At the end of the day, expressions are a syntactic thing, and at the syntactic level, the parser can't tell the return type of methods anyway :D.

Comment: *"... the parser can't tell the return type of methods anyway"* -  Indeed, it is not possible to express (non-trivial) typing using a conventional grammar.  (You need a [two level grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-level_grammar), and they are truly mind-bending.)